# Instantiate an Interface

Tags: java, object, interface, initialization, instantiation

Extending the question asked in [Initializing an Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842085/initializing-an-interface) , we do instantiate an Interface while initialize it with implemented class.

My question is why in the first place, we are instantiate it with the Interface? Why can't I directly instantiate it with implemented class?
For eg. :

```
Doc mydoc = new SimpleDoc();
```

Where Doc is interface and SimpleDoc is implementing it.
What is the problem with 
    SimpleDoc mydoc = new SimpleDoc();
Where this will fail?

Comment: Your question is already answered by the question you link to. BTW: If you actually tried it, you'd notice that it wouldn't fail.

Comment: I didn't get the reason for this question there.

Comment: I agree this wouldn't fail for this example. But I am asking is there any place it might? If not, then why we need the need of lets just say practice of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally good practice to depend on abstract types (interfaces or abstract classes) within a system.

In your example, you could indeed write:

```
SimpleDoc mydoc = new SimpleDoc()
```

However the problem is that code that uses `mydoc` will depend on the concrete type `SimpleDoc`.  This isn't necessarily a problem in itself, however, suppose you create a new implementation of `Doc`, say `ComplexDoc`.

You'd change your declaration to:

```
ComplexDoc mydoc = new ComplexDoc();
```

Now all the places methods that you pass `mydoc` to would also have to change.

However had you used `Doc` in the first place you'd have a single change to make with:

```
Doc mydoc = ComplexDoc();
```

This is particularly useful when you are working with the Collections API, where it's common to switch one implementation of another or when using Mocking in test case.

Comment: Please bear with me for an idea I have. Suppose I create Interface class object and value is coming from a method and that method can return any object class. In that case, it would be useful?

Comment: The import thing is that by depending on an interface, you can switch implementation with minimal bother, though like everything in OO, this has to be used sensibly and when appropriate - deciding went comes down to practice

Answer (score 1):

If you write:

```
SimpleDoc mydoc = new SimpleDoc();
```

all the further code may depend on details exposed by the implementing class `SimpleDoc`. But if you write:

```
Doc mydoc = new SimpleDoc();
```

the further code my only depend on aspects exposed by `Doc`, which make the code even work if you decide in the future to write:

```
Doc mydoc = new ComplexDoc();
```

A good example for the differences is `List`, which has at least two implementations:

```
ArrayList
LinkedList
```

If you write:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

you are free to replace it later with:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
```

without breaking the code relying on the variable `list` (assuming you did not used casts or reflection to access implementation specific features of `list`).

Answer (score 0):

If you uses a interface instead of implementation class in clients code, you are able to change implementation without changing clients code.

Comment: I am not sure I followed you on this.

Answer (score 0):

That is what we called as **Virtual Method Invocation** or **Late Binding**

Let us look at an example.

```
public interface Vegetarian{}
public class Animal{}
public class Deer extends Animal implements Vegetarian{}
```

Now, the Deer class is considered to be **polymorphic** since this has **multiple inheritance**. Following are true for the above example:

```
A Deer IS-A Animal

A Deer IS-A Vegetarian

A Deer IS-A Deer

A Deer IS-A Object
```

When we apply the reference variable facts to a Deer object reference, the following declarations are legal:

```
Deer d = new Deer();
Animal a = d;
Vegetarian v = d;
Object o = d
```

All the reference variables `d,a,v,o` refer to the same `Deer` object in the heap.