# Print (physically) Console in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, printing

I have searched online for how to do this but havent found an answer.

How would I print out the data that is in the console in Eclipse? I do not mean using System.out.print(). I am talking about physically printing it out on paper.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841068/java-printing-program-output-to-a-physical-printer#answer-8853430

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, you can try using the classes in:

[java.awt.print](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/print/package-frame.html)